# cant see smoke in render mode

Tags: smoke-simulation, mantaflow

I cant see smoke in render mode, but i can see in solid mode
[image]

[image]

Comment: and what does your smoke material looks like? Did you change something or is it on default?

Comment: Didn't change anything. Default

Answer (score 0):

Did you use quick smoke to make the smoke? if not you will need a new smoke material, instead of principled bsdf you need to make a principled volume and connect it to the volume shader output. it should look like this

[image: this is how it should look like]